# How to use ajax with asp.net generic Handler (.ashx)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-ajax

What is the proper way of using ajax with a generic Handler. In my scenario I'm passing two arguments, but when the handler is triggered, they (the parameters) enter as null, thus resulting in an error. My code is as follows:

```
//JQUERY
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: PATH_GETNAIC,
                data: JSON.stringify({ category: 1, id: 0 }), //ALSO TRIED USING: "category=1" + "&id=0"
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) { ...

//HANDLER
public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
        string category = context.Request["category"];
        string id = context.Request["id"];

        var result = GetNaicSector(category, id);


        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(result));
    }

    private List<NaicCode> GetNaicSector(string category, string id)
    { ... //RETURNS LIST }
public bool IsReusable {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Can some one point what I'm I doing wrong here. Thanks in advance.
PS: If I execute the handler with respective parameters, it returns the JSON data.

Answer (score 0):

So if it helps anyone, I manage to achieve the ajax call to the Handler by using $.getJSON function; as follows:

```
$.getJSON(PATH_GETNAIC, { category: 1, id: 0 }, function (data) { ...//DO SOMETHING HERE }
```